# Print Python deque items one at a time with all items before it

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, deque

I have created the deque `h = collections.deque()` and appended numbers 1-10 to it and enclosed it the function `print(h)` in the user defined function `Numbers_deque()`. Specifically, I did this:

```
import collections


def Numbers_deque():
    h = collections.deque()
    j = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    h.append(j)
    print(h)

Numbers_deque()
```

What I would like to know is, how would I print out the deque items increasing one at a time, and each time it also prints out all the items before it? For example, each time `Numbers_deque` is called, the first time I want it to print `deque([1])`, then the second time it should print `deque([1,2])`, then the third time it should print `deque([1,2,3])` so on so forth. How would I do this?

Comment: What if you call `Numbers_deque` more than 10 times?

Comment: The `deque` contains a single `tuple` with 10 numbers. Is it really meant to be a `deque` with 10 numbers? You would use `h.extend` instead of `h.append`.

Comment: e.g. To get `deque([1,2,3])` you would have to create a new `deque` with just the elements `1`, `2`, and `3`

Comment: @PeterWood If called more than 10 times, then it should start over.

Comment: @PeterWood Well, if I extended it, then whenever I want to go to the next number with and include the ones before it, I would have to do `print(h)` then extend `h` to another deque with (1,2), `print(h)` again, then extend it over another deque with (1,2,3) so on so forth ten times over. Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: These requirements are very strange. What are you trying to achieve? You need some state, either global, or captured in some way, maybe a generator. There is probably a far easier way to achieve what you really need. Globals are generally evil, and the hoops you'd have to jump through to get a generator to work would make for very complex code.

Comment: Why do you _need_ a `deque`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiate the deque as a default argument. Then it's only done once and is reused on every call to the function.

```
import collections


def Numbers_deque(h = collections.deque()):
    if len(h) >= 10:
        h.clear()
    h.append(len(h)+1)
    print(h)

Numbers_deque()
```

But be careful if you are going to return the deque and use it outside the function. Then you should make a copy

Comment: This works, but it prints it out all at once. What I want is that it should print **one** of the results every time it is called by the user, for example if the user calls the `Numbers_deque` function in the shell, or every time a certain key is pressed that calls the function.

Comment: Ok. I removed the for loop to make it equal the code in question